# Is it possible to use Nano with mblock and oldbootler?

Tags: atmega328, uploading

I've old Nanos that to program (upload) with Arduino IDE I have to select "ATMEGA328P Old Bootloader".   The programming is via the standard Nano USB cable, and I need the CH340 driver under Windows 7.

With mblock (ide) I've selected the nano device package, but when I go to program the nano with the scratch program, the COM port is available, but the device is never found.   I suspect this is due to the old bootloader.  Is there a way to make use of the old bootloader under mblock?

[At this time not looking to re-flash my Nanos with a separate programmer.]
TIA.

Comment: *"TIA"* <- I hated this before I bothered looking it up. Anyway, I've never heard of this thing before. The developers section of the website seems to take me to a login screen in Chinese which isn't helpful. My only suggestion is it that if it claims to support Diecimila with 328P maybe try that. So far as I can tell they're largely compatible board definitions. If it works for you can write your own answer or someone can turn it into a community answer or whatever.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to send makeblock the question...  But maybe new Nano's are the price I need to pay...

Comment: I'm taking the above to mean that you did *not* find Diecimila as an option. Re: *"separate programmer"*. You understand that a "programmer" can be one of your Nanos, some jumpers, a breadboard, and a capacitor with the [ArduinoISP](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP) sketch? So, if you're about saving money, you don't necessarily need to buy anything. Anyway, that's all I have to offer.